# getting javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: exception while encrypting the encrypted data

Tags: java

when i tried encrypting and decrypting the data using RSA its works fine .

Here c is the user defined class which has rsaEncrypt and rsaDecrypt methods.

```
byte b[]=c.rsaEncrypt("voterpublickey.key",(""+randomnumber).getBytes(),"public")<br>
new String(c.rsaDecrypt("voterprivatekey.key",b,"private"));
```

but here i need to do this E(priv(LA), E(Pub(VF), vnumber))  encryption using RSA .
But it raising an error at both encrypt and decrypt.

while encrypting

```
b=c.rsaEncrypt("vfpublickey.key",(vnumber+"").getBytes(),"public");
b=c.rsaEncrypt("laprivatekey.key",b,"private");
```

```
stacktrace:
    javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 245 bytes
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:344)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
        at cli.rsaEncrypt(cli.java:79)
        at LaSer.main(LaSer.java:108)
```

while decrypting

```
byte b[]=c.rsaDecrypt("lapublickey.key",b,"public");
new String(c.rsaDecrypt("vfprivatekey.key",b,"private"));
```

```
stacktrace:
    javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
        at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:380)
        at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:291)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:363)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
        at cli.rsaDecrypt(cli.java:99)
        at ConnectionWithLaser.run(VfSer.java:371)
```

am i doing anything wrong.is encrypting the encrypted data is right?

is there is any method to handle this situation ?

updated:

```
PrivateKey readKeyFromFileDecrypt(String keyFileName) throws IOException {
  InputStream in =
    cli.class.getResourceAsStream(keyFileName);
  ObjectInputStream oin =
    new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(in));
  try {
    BigInteger m = (BigInteger) oin.readObject();
    BigInteger e = (BigInteger) oin.readObject();
    RSAPrivateKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(m, e);
    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey priKey = fact.generatePrivate(keySpec);
    return priKey;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Spurious serialisation error", e);
  } finally {
    oin.close();
  }
}
//similar function readKeyFromFileEncrypt
public byte[] rsaEncrypt(String keyFileName,byte[] data,String key)throws Exception {
if(key.equals("public")){
  PublicKey pubKey = readKeyFromFileEncrypt(keyFileName);
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
}
else if(key.equals("private"))
{
  PrivateKey priKey = readKeyFromFileDecrypt(keyFileName);
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, priKey);
}
  byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(data);
  return cipherData;
}
public byte[] rsaDecrypt(String keyFileName,byte[] data,String key)throws Exception{
if(key.equals("public")){
  PublicKey pubKey = readKeyFromFileEncrypt(keyFileName);
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
  cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
}
else if(key.equals("private"))
{
  PrivateKey priKey = readKeyFromFileDecrypt(keyFileName);
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
  cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, priKey);

}
  byte[] originalData = cipher.doFinal(data);
  return originalData;
}
```

and finally while generating public and private key

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(2048);
KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
Key publicKey = kp.getPublic();
Key privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
```

Comment: Please provide the code for `rsaEncrypt`/`rsaDecrypt`. You should not encrypt arbitrary amounts of data with a raw rsa function as that is quite expensive and limited by the size of the modulus. Usually a symmetric key is generated and rsa-encrypted while a symmetric encryption like AES is used for content encryption (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem)

Comment: i updated the post with rsaEncrypt and rsaDecrypt methods.

Answer (score 0):

basically your code is fine.

I reproduced your issue with the following code:

```
package foo;

import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;

public class FooTest
{
    
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance( "RSA" );
        int keysize = 2048;
        kpg.initialize( keysize );
        KeyPair keys = kpg.genKeyPair();
        
        SecureRandom rng = new SecureRandom();
        
        byte[] data = new byte[keysize / 8 - 11];
        rng.nextBytes( data );
        
        // "encryption"
        byte[] cipherText = encrypt( data, keys.getPublic() );
        byte[] decrypted = decrypt( cipherText, keys.getPrivate() );
        
        if ( !Arrays.equals( data, decrypted ) )
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException( "decrypted was not equal to message" );
        }
        
        // "signature"
        cipherText = encrypt( data, keys.getPrivate() );
        decrypted = decrypt( cipherText, keys.getPublic() );
        
        if ( !Arrays.equals( data, decrypted ) )
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException( "decrypted was not equal to message" );
        }
        
        data = new byte[keysize / 8 - 10];
        rng.nextBytes( data );
        try
        {
            encrypt( data, keys.getPublic() );
        }
        catch ( IllegalBlockSizeException e )
        {
            System.err.println( "data size of " + data.length + " may not exceed " + (keysize / 8 - 11) );
        }
    }
    
    static byte[] encrypt( byte[] data, Key key ) throws Exception
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance( "RSA" );
        cipher.init( Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key );
        
        return cipher.doFinal( data );
    }
    
    static byte[] decrypt( byte[] data, Key key ) throws Exception
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance( "RSA" );
        cipher.init( Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key );
        
        return cipher.doFinal( data );
    }
}
```

[RFC 3447](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-7.2.1) describes why the limit is 11 bytes lower than the actual keysize.